# Pod stuck in "Terminating" state

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I recently had cause to restart a fluentd-elasticsearch pod for all my nodes.  Out of 7 nodes where the pods were deleted only 1 of them deleted and came back as "Running".  Is there a way to completely purge a pod in k8s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fluentd-elasticsearch` pods are [static pods](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4ca66d2aefa20c27b670b2fa890052daadc05294/docs/admin/static-pods.md) which are created via placing pod manifest files (`fluentd-es.yaml`) in a directory watched by Kubelet. The corresponding pod (a.k.a. the *mirror pod*) with the same name and namespace in the API server is created automatically for the purpose of introspection -- it reflects the status of the static pod.

Kubernetes treats the static pod (the pod manifest file) in the directory as the source of the truth; operations (deletion/update, etc) on the mirror pod will *not* have any effect on the static pod.

You are encouraged to move away from static pods and use [DaemonSet](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4ca66d2aefa20c27b670b2fa890052daadc05294/docs/admin/daemons.md), except for a few particular use cases (e.g., standalone Kubelets). The system add-on pods such as `fluentd-elasticsearch` will be converted to `DaemonSet` eventually.

Comment: Also, if you modified a mirror pod by accident., you can forcibly delete it from the etcd by `kubectl delete pod --grace-period=0 <pod_name>`. The mirror pod will be recreated automatically. Note that, again, this has no impact on the actual containers on the node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the cause. But I fixed it by moving /etc/kubernetes/manifests/fluentd-es.yaml to a temp dir, killing the running containers, and moving it back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug this pod, read [K8s user guide for debugging pods](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/application-troubleshooting.html#debugging-pods). You may try `kubectl describe pod` or `kubectl log pods` to see what went wrong.

Note that it's recommended to use [replication controller](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/replication-controller.html) to manager your pods, if you haven't already. It makes sure that a specified number of pods are running at any one time. If a pod is deleted, the replication controller will create one for you.